# US Map w/State Boundaries - Change Colors According to Computed Values

Tags: mysql, dictionary, colors

I am using MySQL to perform some in-depth data analysis, and would like to have the ability to create a color-coded map of the US where the colors of the individual states would be set based upon value ranges; any ideas?  Management loves colors, and the ability to easily summarize the data geographically would be a hit for them. My immediate need is to create documents with these maps on a weekly basis, so the more I can automate this, the better.

```
State     Value  Color
-----     -----  -----
Alaska    25%    red
Alabama   90%    green
Arizona   15%    red
Arkansas  55%    yellow
```

...and so on. I just need something that will take this data and produce a color-coded maps that I can insert into a document or a presentation. Because of this, a web-based solution will not work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Google Charts API to generate a map, I can't really give you an example because the question gives no indication as to what table structure you are working with, or indeed languages, however this could all be done in JavaScript to a JSON API on a webserver...

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart

Comment: My intent is to, for each criteria being measured, boil my data down to a single value for each state. I would then feed this data into a mapping system, which sets colors according to the values. Perhaps this table (above) might help illustrate what I have to present.